# Sending data through Segments in Ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am currently trying to send one ion-card from segment "borradores" to "enviados" with the click of a button, but I don't know how can I pass it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTMcG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NavParams for sending data to another page

In page "Borradores"

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
pushObjToNextPage(objData) {
    this.navCtrl.push(Anotherpage,objData);
    this.navCtrl.push(Anotherpage,objData2);
}
```

In Page Enviados

```
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams) {
    objData: string = this.navParams.get('objData');
    objData2: string = this.navParams.get('objData2');
}
```

- while get and push must be same name of variable

then use objData for show that card again.

see more : https://alligator.io/ionic/navigating-passing-data-ionic/

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: ur welcome next time don't forget to make a cleary question :)